# open source solution to upload 10gb (more than 2gb) files to web app

Tags: file, web-applications, file-upload, applet

As in title needs to be from a web browser ideally it should not be flash. Have looked at writing this myself as a java applet but there is no need to reinvent the weel have searched online but havn't found anything suitable. (for example have seen commons file upload, and a few others). All it needs to do is have acsess to the file on the client's computer split it into chunks and pass to the server Ideally it would do multiple streams.

Comment: *"a java applet but there is no need to reinvent the weel have searched online but havn't found anything suitable."* Which would tend to suggest you are not reinventing this particular applet.  Go for it.  And open source it so other people who have need for large uploads can benefit.

Comment: I am convinced that something like this exists as I have seen it used before Im' not toally adverse to paying but I tend to like open source projects while I have searched I havn't spent hours  and hours searching. basically more of a 'have anyone head of' thread

Answer (score 2):

Try out JumpLoader, it's a Java uploader that will chunk larger files so that they may be uploaded without being limited by your web server's max file size.